# Error executing action `create` on resource 'directory[C:/topdir/subdir]'

Tags: windows, chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook, recipe

I'm getting permissions errors with the create action on windows servers.

Initially I was doing this in one recipe:

```
directory "C:/topdir" do
  rights :full_control, 'Users'
  action :create
end
 directory "C:/topdir/subdir" do
    action :create
    recursive true
  end
```

If I run this in test kitchen or even login to a bootstrapped server and run chef-client it completes with no errors.

But I see these errors on Chef server when it runs automatically:

```
Description: Error executing action `create` on resource 'directory[C:/topdir/subdir]'
Chef::Exceptions::InsufficientPermissions
Cannot create directory[C:/topdir/subdir] at C:/topdir/subdir due to insufficient permissions
```

It seems I "fixed" this by replacing `rights :fullcontrol, 'Users'` with `rights :fullcontrol, 'Everyone'` but I don't want that and it doesn't make sense to me why that would be necessary.

Why is this happening?

Also, how can I test this if the errors only happen during automated chef runs- I can only see errors in chef server reporting. How can I see what user this is even running in? I assumed local system but I guess not? It works running chef-client locally from an elevated prompt so why would it not work when running on schedule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My knowledge of Windows is limited, but in general I think services get run as a dedicated SYSTEM user, which is not part of the Users group.

Comment: I thought this was it but after adding the SYSTEM user to topdir the error is still happening. What is weird is that chef still sets the permissions if I change the config so it can access it, but its still throwing permissions errors